# Plot quiver polar coordinates

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the field distribution inside a circular structure with radius `a`.
What I expect to see are circular arrows that from the centre `0` go toward `a` in the radial direction like this
[image]

but I'm obtaining something far from this result. I wrote this

```
x_np = besselzero(n, p, 1); %toolbox from mathworks.com for the roots
R = 0.1:1:a; PHI = 0:pi/180:2*pi;

for r = 1:size(R,2)
    for phi = 1:size(PHI,2)
        u_R(r,phi) = -1/2*((besselj(n-1,x_np*R(1,r)/a)-besselj(n+1,x_np*R(1,r)/a))/a)*cos(n*PHI(1,phi));
        u_PHI(r,phi) = n*(besselj(n,x_np*R(1,r)/a)/(x_np*R(1,r)))*sin(PHI(1,phi));
    end
end


[X,Y] = meshgrid(R);
quiver(X,Y,u_R,u_PHI)
```

where `u_R` is supposed to be the radial component and `u_PHI` the angular component. Supposing the formulas that I'm writing are correct, do you think there is a problem with `for` cycles? Plus, since R and PHI are not with the same dimension (in this case R is 1x20 and PHI 1X361) I also get the error

```
The size of X must match the size of U or the number of columns of U.
```

that I hope to solve it if I figure out which is the problem with the cycles.
This is the plot that I get
[image]

Comment: This question may be answered on the [Matlab forum](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/178279-plotting-a-vector-field-in-polar-coordinates)

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with a difference in co-ordinate systems.

`quiver` expects inputs in a Cartesian co-ordinate system.

The rest of your code seems to be expressed in a polar co-ordinate system.

Here's a snippet that should do what you want. The initial parameters section is filled in with random values because I don't have `besselzero` or the other details of your problem.

```
% Define initial parameters
x_np = 3;
a = 1;
n = 1;

% Set up domain (Cartesian)
x = -a:0.1:a;
y = -a:0.1:a;

[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);

% Allocate output
U = zeros(size(X));
V = zeros(size(X));

% Loop over each point in domain
for ii = 1:length(x)
    for jj = 1:length(y)
        % Compute polar representation
        r = norm([X(ii,jj), Y(ii,jj)]);
        phi = atan2(Y(ii,jj), X(ii,jj));

        % Compute polar unit vectors
        rhat = [cos(phi); sin(phi)];
        phihat = [-sin(phi); cos(phi)];

        % Compute output (in polar co-ordinates)
        u_R = -1/2*((besselj(n-1, x_np*r/a)-besselj(n+1, x_np*r/a))/a)*cos(n*phi);
        u_PHI = n*(besselj(n, x_np*r/a)/(x_np*r))*sin(phi);

        % Transform output to Cartesian co-ordinates
        U(ii,jj) = u_R*rhat(1) + u_PHI*phihat(1);
        V(ii,jj) = u_R*rhat(2) + u_PHI*phihat(2);
    end
end

% Generate quiver plot
quiver(X, Y, U, V);
```